# C# How to correctly modify IntPtr and Marshal.Copy to switch from int to long?

Tags: c#, pointers, optimization

The code in question (below) reads much faster (30x), tahn regular: MemoryMappedViewAccessor.ReadArray()
I'm trying to modify the code to be able to read from **long** offset, **not int** (!)

```
    public unsafe byte[] ReadBytes(int offset, int num)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[num];
        byte *ptr = (byte*)0;
        this._view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref ptr);
        Marshal.Copy(IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(ptr), offset), arr, 0, num);
        this._view.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
        return arr;
    }
```

original code is here:
[How can I quickly read bytes from a memory mapped file in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956167/how-can-i-quickly-read-bytes-from-a-memory-mapped-file-in-net#_=)_

I need to adjust IntPtr.Add and Marshal.Copy to correctly work with **long offset**
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need to have a `long` offset. You can chunk your long value into integers and iterate over those values.

Comment: Dear Eldar! Thank you for a prompt reply -
As I see Marshal.Copy copies a pointer to specific location - 
I see no way to iterate as int-s - please explain your idea!

Comment: With the help of this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219932/12354911). Let's assume your offset is now two integer values so your final pointer will be sth like this :`var finalPtr =IntPtr.Add(IntPtr.Add(new IntPtr(ptr), offsets[0]),offsets[1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new IntPtr(intPtr.ToInt64() + longOffset)`

Of course, this works in 64 bit processes only.

Comment: U r the life saver! Works like a charm:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Klaus Gütter!
Complete working code, based on your suggested method:

```
public static unsafe byte[] ReadBytes(long l_offset, int i_read_buf_size, MemoryMappedViewAccessor mmva)
    {
        byte[] arr = new byte[i_read_buf_size];
        byte* ptr = (byte*)0;
        mmva.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.AcquirePointer(ref ptr);
        IntPtr p = new(ptr);
        Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(p.ToInt64() + l_offset), arr, 0, i_read_buf_size);
        mmva.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle.ReleasePointer();
        return arr;
    }
```